# How do I hide the cancel button in a custom DialogPreference in Android?

Tags: android, android-dialog

How do I hide the cancel button in a custom DialogPreference in Android?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Override onPrepareDialogBuilder and set it to null there.

```
/** Hide the cancel button */
@Override
protected void onPrepareDialogBuilder(Builder builder) {
    super.onPrepareDialogBuilder(builder);
    builder.setNegativeButton(null, null);
}
```